# How to handle different versions of data in spring batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a situation where I need to read the data from the different versions of the application where the data is stored in the database and write it into a flat file. I’ll be using spring batch to implement this scenario. However in couple of tables we have more columns compared to the old version.

Example: let’s say table1 in version 1.0.0 has column1, column2 and same table1 in the version 1.0.1 has column1, column2, column3.

Let’s say customer 1 has version 1.0.0 and customer 2 has version 1.0.1. We want to write a common solution where we can extract the data from dB and write it into a flat file. The flat file can have the all the three columns irrespective of the customer version but the values should be null if customer is in 1.0.0.

How can we use spring batch to handle both the versions.

Comment: I would version the batch app accordingly and deploy/run the one that corresponds to the right db schema.

Comment: The problem is I have very long list of application version (nearly 8+).

Answer (score 2):

You could implement different ItemReaders for each version of the database and then use a property in your application.yml file (eg. database.version) to work out which ItemReader to create and use in the Step.

Comment: Do you have any sample code or any source link where I can go through it?